# How to return redux state from async function?

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await

My reducer is not able to return the correct state. I get a promise when accessing weather from my other components. I used async await in the getWeather function but I'm not sure why I still get a promise from the return value.

```
const initState = {
    date: new Date(),
    weather: "",
};

const getWeather = async (difference) => {
    await fetch(
        "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=1.290270&lon=103.851959&%20exclude=hourly,daily&appid=" +
            WEATHER_API_KEY
    )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            return data["daily"][difference]["weather"][0]["main"];
        });
};

export default function (state = initState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case DATE_SELECT:
            const day_difference =
                moment(action.payload).date() - moment(state.date).date();
            return {
                date: action.payload,
                weather: getWeather(day_difference),
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Redux` by default doesn't support async actions. You will need a middleware such as `redux-thunk` to support it.

Basically you will need a function to fetch the weather data that dispatch another action when the data is resolved, something like:

```
// Get weather need to be a function that return an action    
const getWeather = (difference) => {
        return (dispatch) => fetch(
            "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=1.290270&lon=103.851959&%20exclude=hourly,daily&appid=" +
                WEATHER_API_KEY
        )
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                // Dispatch a function with the weather data
                dispatch("RECEIVE_WEATHER", data["daily"][difference]["weather"][0]["main"]);
            });
    };
```

An example on the topic can be found on the redux doc website: https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions

Answer (score 1):

`async function` always returns a promise. [Read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

So to handle your case, you have to use some middleware to handle side effect like [Redux thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) or [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/)